# Enable a second monitor on a remote computer

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I have set up a local remote desktop connection between my Thinkpad and my desktop computer, both running Windows 8 Pro. My desktop computer is connected to my TV via HDMI.

What I want to do is to use the laptop as a remote control for my desktop, so I don't always have to get up from the couch to use the mouse or keyboard on the desktop if it requires interaction. However I can't seem to activate the TV as a second screen of the desktop if I'm connected via remote. In the Control Panel where you usually can set up screens and resolutions, all controls are disabled along with a "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session" message. It doesn't work via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or the Charms bar either.

My question now is, whether this is actually possible with a remote desktop session. If not, is this possible at all, maybe with different software such as VNC or Teamviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works via Teamviewer 8, however if there is a possibility to do it with the Windows remote desktop, I'd be still interested in that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done with default RDP client, but with certain limitations.
Since this is included in OS and is actually free - this is Ok.

Specifically, the client needs the following for span mode to work correctly:

- Equal resolution monitors
- Total resolution of all monitors not exceeding 4096 x 2048
- Top-left monitor being the primary

Besides, you need to have MS RDP Client ver.6 installed.

If you go to `Run` > and type in `mstsc /?` - you will get basic help for rdp client

[image]

[`Here`](http://www.splitview.com/using-remote-desktop-with-dual-monitors-in-span-mode) is an article which describes all the requirements\limitations\configuration instructions in details.

Comment: I'm not sure if that does what I want. I have no additional monitors connected to my laptop, and only want to change the output device of the remote computer.

Comment: You do not have to have additional monitors connected to your laptop. Span mode is responsible for viewing multiple remote displays on a local machine while certain conditions are preserved (Review this article to understand differences between multimon feature vs "span" mode).http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the `/span` works. Now, how would spell it out in the `.rdp` file so I don't have to enter the command by hand next time? Is it simply `span=1` or something hairier?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding `span:i:1` to the RDP-file and it worked. Now I can just click on the desktop icon and span is enabled...